# Mysql query between 3 date ranges

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a php script that allows a user to generate reports, they have the option of selecting 3 date ranges.
i.e.

```
2012-01-01 to 2012-01-31
AND 
2011-01-01 to 2011-01-31
AND 
2010-01-01 to 2010-01-31
```

But when I do my query, and there are no records between a certain date range, the query returns no values.

Here is my query:

```
 SELECT DealerName WHERE InterviewDate >= "2012/01/01 " AND InterviewDate <= " 2012/03/31"
 AND InterviewDate >= "2012/07/01 " AND InterviewDate <= " 2012/09/31"
```

I need a query that will return data if it is found in 1 of the date ranges, regardless of whether there is no data in the subsequent date ranges.

The data is summarized into a table where it would be possible for a the same data to be on multiple dates.

for example:

```
dealerName 1    2012-01-01
dealerName 1    2012-02-31
dealerName 2    2012-03-01
dealerName 1    2012-06-01
dealerName 1    2012-06-31
```

So If I wanted to query the data between 2012-01-01 and 2012-02-31 AND 2012-06-01 AND 2012-06-31.  I realise that 1 date range could encompass all of these ranges, but the user may want to exclude data between these two date ranges.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A interview date can not be between x and y AND still be between z and zz. You are missing a `OR` - Also, have a look at the `BETWEEN` operator

```
SELECT DealerName
FROM table
WHERE InterviewDate BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-01-31'
    OR InterviewDate BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-01-31'
    OR InterviewDate BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2010-01-31'
```

edit, sorry, missed the table name :)

Comment: @HamletHakobyan fingers to quick for brain, missed the FROM clause :) Thanks!

Comment: The data is summarised into a table where it is possible for the records to appear on more than 1 date.

Comment: @user1882752 one _single row_ can not be between more than one range at the time, since they are not overlapping. Say you have a red shirt on. Which statement is true? "You have a red shirt AND a green shirt AND a blue shirt on" or "You have a red shirt OR a green shirt OR a blue shirt on"?

Comment: @hank thank you, this works. (I have face palmed myself repeatedly for not seeing the obvious)

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `OR` instead of `AND`

```
WHERE   (InterviewDate BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-01-31')
        OR
        (InterviewDate BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-01-31')
        OR
        (InterviewDate BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2010-01-31')
```

**UPDATE 1**

i think you have the `Relational Division` problem,

```
SELECT name
FROM   table1
WHERE  DATE BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-02-31'
       OR
       DATE BETWEEN '2012-06-01' AND '2012-06-31'
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d737c/1)
- [SQL of Relational Division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

Comment: Wouldnt OR take 1 range OR the other, not both?

Comment: i have a question for you, lets say you have an `InterviewDate` of `2012-01-15`, how can it be present on year `2011` or `2010`?

Comment: I think brackets redundant.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan yes, but it's for clarity purposes. anyway it will not affect the performance.

Comment: @JW, I have edited an explanation of how the data is repeated

Comment: @user1882752 you have a dealer which is present in all your interview dates right? and you want to find that.

Answer (score 4):

Why not using OR instead of AND ?

```
SELECT DealerName WHERE ( InterviewDate >= "2012/01/01 " AND InterviewDate <= " 2012/03/31" )  OR ( InterviewDate >= "2012/07/01 " AND InterviewDate <= " 2012/09/31" )
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `OR` instead of `AND`

```
SELECT DealerName FROM tbl
WHERE InterviewDate >= '2012/01/01' AND InterviewDate <= '2012/03/31'
 OR InterviewDate >= '2012/07/01' AND InterviewDate <= '2012/09/31'
```

Comment: The problem is I need to query the database over all the ranges, not just on 1 set of ranges

Comment: @user1882752 Of course, for all ranges. This query will returns all rows that belong to any of the range.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take away :) since you are checking on the `month` of January for `year` 2010, 2011, 2012. We can use [`MONTH`](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-month-function.php) and [`YEAR`](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-year-function.php) functions.

```
SELECT DealerName
FROM yourtable
WHERE Month(InterviewDate) = 1
AND Year(InterviewDate) IN (2010, 2011, 2012)
;

SELECT DealerName
FROM yourtable
WHERE Month(InterviewDate) IN (1, 2) // if there are particular months
AND Year(InterviewDate) IN (2010, 2011, 2012)
;
```

Comment: Please englighten me on the `index` part. Why do you say it will kill the index? I don't see that OP is mentioning about `index` columns.